# Apart from the KE of the positron and neutrino, where does the remaining transition energy go during beta-plus decay?

Tags: radiation

Apart from the KE of the positron and neutrino, where does the remaining transition energy go during beta-plus decay? What is the 1.022 MeV minimum energy transition used for?

Comment: Surely the positron is stable. It does decay, but rather get annihilated when it meets an electron.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused! Is 0.511 MeV "used" to create the positron? I'm still unsure about the additional 0.511 MeV energy requirement for the extra electron in the daughter atom. Any further clarification would be great. @JonCuster

Comment: The 1.022 MeV is what you get when you add up the stuff on the right hand side and substract the (arbitrarily neutral) daughter isotope, so you know that everything on the left hand side has to have a total mass-energy at least 1.022 MeV bigger than the neutral daughter isotope for the decay to happen. I'd suggest "x particle accounts for y amount of energy" as a more useful phrasing than "y amount of energy is used to create x particle".